# java ArrayList clone several times

Tags: java, arraylist, clone

I am trying to clone my `ArrayList` 4 times using a `for-loop` and `clone()` method, but I could not.
The below is the (straightforward) code I wrote:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> newArrList;
    for (int n = 1; n <= 4; n++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
            arrList.add(i);
        }
        newArrList = (ArrayList<Integer>) arrList.clone();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
            newArrList.add(i);
        }
    }
```

The output is:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`
It prints my `arrList` only 2 times, but I want it 4 times. Like that:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`

Is it the best way to clone an `ArrayList` multiple times? and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't call what you have done "straightforward" ;-)

Comment: @mastov: I am trying my best! - can you see where I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems a little too confusing to me, so I'm unable to point out where exactly you went wrong.

The first thing I don't understand is why you create your test list 4 times (inside the main loop). Shouldn't it be created just once?

Then doing a `clone` and adding the 13 elements afterwards put the content twice in the new list. Once as a copy of the original content, and then as hard-coded data. I don't understand the motivation behind that.

Anyway, I would just create a new (empty) list and add all the elements of the original list 4 times using `addAll`:

```
// create test list
ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
    arrList.add(i);
}

// clone
ArrayList<Integer> newArrList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    newArrList.addAll(arrList);
}
```

Comment: This is `straightforward` and `better` code. Thanks for that.

Comment: @dustin Sorry for not being able to explain exactly what's wrong with your code. I just don't understand it enough.